# Wget stuck on awaiting response

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing

I have a server, client and a virtual SRX between them. I'm trying to `wget` a pdf file from server to client, but it gets stuck on `Http request sent. Awaiting response.` All traffic is meant to go out of the server/client into the SRX then to the server/client. I'm trying to figure out how to fix this and send/receive traffic.

Both the client and the server are running Ubuntu 14.04. I have changed the IP routes to facilitate the data transfer. I am able to ping but nothing more. I have noticed that I am unable to connect to the internet:

```
ping www.google.com
```

fails. I have also used

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

to ensure port 80 is open on both. To my knowledge this seems to be an issue because of the lack of internet connectivity. I am new to Ubuntu and IP routes/tables and suspect that my config is what is causing the issue.

**IP routes on Client:**

> default via 4.0.0.254 dev eth4
>
> default via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0
>
> 4.0.0.0/24 dev eth4 proto kernel scope link src 4.0.0.101
>
> 5.0.0.0/24 via 4.0.0.1 dev eth4
>
> 5.0.0.0/8 dev eth4 scope link
>
> 6.0.0.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 6.0.0.101
>
> 7.0.0.0/8 via 6.0.0.1 dev eth2
>
> 10.2.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.205.106
>
> 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.101
>
> 192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.3.1 dev eth3

**IP Routes on Server:**

> default via 5.0.0.254 dev eth4
>
> default via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0
>
> 4.0.0.0/8 via 5.0.0.254 dev eth4
>
> 5.0.0.0/24 dev eth4 proto kernel scope link src 5.0.0.101
>
> 6.0.0.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 6.0.0.101
>
> 7.0.0.0/8 via 6.0.0.1 dev eth2
>
> 10.2.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.206.107
>
> 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.101
>
> 192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.3.1 dev eth3

The default gateway is `10.2.0.1` and the name servers are `10.2.0.11` and `10.2.0.12`.

I expect to be able to transfer the file across without any errors. From client to server, I'm unable to even connect. From server to client, I'm stuck at awaiting response.

I can edit and add additional details if required.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lPs2.jpg) of `ifconfig -a` on client and server

Comment: Solved. Removed the routes from the interfaces I'm not using to make the table more readable. Removed the 5.0.0.0/8 entry. The places it says 4.0.0.1 and 5.0.0.1 are supposed to be 4.0.0.101 and 5.0.0.101 - Silly mistake. Devices able to execute wget and data passes through the SRX to Sky ATP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Removed the routes from the interfaces I'm not using to make the table more readable. Removed the 5.0.0.0/8 entry. The places it says 4.0.0.1 and 5.0.0.1 are supposed to be 4.0.0.101 and 5.0.0.101 - Silly mistake. Devices able to execute wget and data passes through the SRX to Sky ATP.